# Search for values in a list using a for loop and print the search result

Tags: python, pandas

I am searching for documents in a folder that has many subfolders. For this I'm using

```
def find_all(name, path):
   result = []
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
      if name in files:
         result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
   print(result)
find_all(name, "path_here")
```

Then I have a list of document names in excel that I want to search for in the folder.

```
d = {'doc_id': [123456, 289456, 654987, 128984, 980524]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to use a `for loop` to iterate through each `doc_id` and make it the `name` variable in the `find_all` function.

```
for doc in df:
   name = doc
```

I'm not sure how to piece these two together and print the result in a new column next to each doc_id.
So the result would possibly look like

```
df
doc_id     result
123456      n/a
289456     "folder named here that doc was found in"
654987      n/a
128984     "folder named here that doc was found in"
980524     "folder named here that doc was found in"
```

Comment: `for doc in df['doc_id']` would work in your case.

Comment: If your function doesn't `return` anything, then you will either get a column of `None` or you'll have to do some funky thing like piping the result of the `print()` statement to a string then assigning the string to the dataframe. Also, iterating over dataframe values is almost never the best option in pandas, look into using `apply()` to apply the function to the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
l=[i for i in os.walk('your_main_path_here')]

def path_of_file(file):
    for i in l:
        if file in i[2]:
            return i[0]
    return 'n/a'

df['result']=''
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.result.iloc[i]=path_of_file(df.doc_id.iloc[i])
```

Alternatively the new column can be filled with these 2 ways (recommended if the dataframe is too long):

with apply:

```
df['result']=df['doc_id'].apply(lambda x: path_of_file(x))
```

With map:

```
df['result']=[i for i in map(path_of_file, df['doc_id'])]
```

Comment: Does the ```df['result']``` and ```for loop``` go inside of the ```name_path``` function?

Comment: Give me a minute, i will return with a complete solution. Can you confirm that all that you want is that second column with the filepath for every file in first column, no matter the way it will be achieved?

Comment: yep, that's all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `for i in range(len(df)):` with `iloc` instead of the built-in method `apply()` to apply the function to the dataframe?

Comment: Yeah, i have add this option too, as well as the map option, in case the df is too long

Comment: I am getting the error ```string index out of range``` and points to ```return 'n/a'```

Comment: Strange. Was the list l created correctly? Did you try some of the other 2 options?